# Tkinter window when using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a .py script that autofill some forms using Selenium. In the start of the code, I used Tkinter extension to use the messagebox and filedialog function.

My code runs fine, but everytime I got an annoying window called "tk" (I guess it is related to Tkinter). This window is blank, but I would like to remove it from my code run.

Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: First create a `tkinter.Tk()` then call `<tkinter.Tk>.withdraw()` to hide the window. When you are done with the `filedialog`, call `<tkinter.Tk>.destroy()` to destroy the window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

# Create a dummy window
root = tk.Tk()
# Hide the window
root.withdraw()

# Use `filedialog` freely
print(filedialog.askopenfilename())

# If you want to destroy the window at the end.
# You don't have to
root.destroy()
```

The reason why that window appears is linked to how tkinter handles new windows. It uses `tkinter.Toplevel` instead of a `tkinter.Tk`. But a `tkinter.Toplevel` can't exist without a `tkinter.Tk` so it creates one. That is the window that you see.

To hide the window you have to first create your own `tkinter.Tk` and hide it using `<tkinter.Tk>.withdraw()`.

Comment: In single lines: `tk.Tk().withdraw()` and then the rest

Comment: @CoolCloud Does `.withdraw()` return the `<tkinter.Tk>` object? Edit: Just checked it. It returns an empty string so you can't call `root.destroy()`

Comment: It does not, but that does not matter. Because a reference does not have to be stored here. Just the tcl interpreter have to be created explicitly, so as to just hide it out.

Comment: @CoolCloud You can't call `root.destroy()` if you don't keep a reference

Comment: You don't have to call `root.destroy()` it automatically destroys when the window is destroyed.

Comment: @CoolCloud If you don't call `.destroy()` you will have a hidden window until the program ends. It's bad practise to have hidden windows/widgets that aren't going to be used but still taking up resources

Comment: That is true. But I was talking about your example, where it does not take up much resource and directly ends the code after the filedialog chose.

Comment: @CoolCloud I am assuming that OP has a lot of code that follows the `filedialog`. Also anyone looking at this in the future, it would be better if I provide code with best practises.

Comment: I agree, it's best to explictly create a root window, and to keep a reference to it.